# How to select two elements? CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm building a navigation and inside of my `ul` list there is another sub-list:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="recipe.html">Cooking</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="recipe.html">Fantasy</a></li>
                <li><a href="recipe.html">Meal</a></li>
                <li><a href="recipe.html">Difficulty</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>other li</li>
     </ul>
```

I basically want it so that every time I hover over the different `li` elements (fantasy-meal-difficulty) an icon at the bottom of the `ul`-list appears.

I'm using `ul::after` to place these icons. The only problem is that they should change when hovering a different `li`.

How should I select them?

Is there any kind of way to select the `ul::after` + `li:nth-child(1)`?

Also, I can't modify my HTML because I'm building a theme for WordPress.

Comment: why not placing the icons inside the li? it will be easier, then change the CSS to place it where you want

Comment: Do you mean selecting multiple elements like
.firstSelector, .secondSelector, .thirdSelector{ color:#fff; }
?

Comment: Can you use js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/txcbdu0f/1/

```
ul.menu li:after{
  content:"";
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#ccc;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-50px;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
}
ul.menu li:hover:after{opacity:1;}
ul.menu li:first-child:hover:after{background:#000;}
ul.menu li:nth-child(2):hover:after{background:#ccc;}
ul.menu li:last-child:hover:after{background:red;}
ul.menu{position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your js fiddle for hover list:
https://jsfiddle.net/txcbdu0f/2/

```
ul ul.menu {
 display: none;
}

ul > li:hover > ul.menu {
 display: block;
}
```

Hope you are looking for this simple idea.